# How To Set Sources For Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, django, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've just bought a new computer, and can't remember/don't know how I had Jupyter notebooks set up on my old machine. Specifically, how do you tell Jupyter about sources.
If I have a conda environment called django, and I do `source activate django` followed by `jupyter notebook`, I end up with a notebook, but then when I do `from django.http import HttpResponse` I get the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Which is bizarre (I think), because Django is definitely installed in the Django environment.

How do I set up my Jupyter notebooks so that they know about the various sources that I want them to know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html).

```
source activate django
conda install ipykernal
python -m ipykernel install --user --name django --display-name "Python (Django)"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely your conda environment `django` doesn't have iPython Kernel installed which jupyter notebook needs. You can run `jupyter notebook` without activating a conda environment as notebook allows you to select any conda environment with `ipykernel` installed.

Try:

1. run in terminal : `source activate django`
2. run in terminal : `conda install ipykernel`
3. run in terminal : `source deactivate`
4. run in terminal : `jupyter notebook`
5. select `django` for your kernel
   [image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with conda. Does creating the `django` virtual environment in conda automatically create the `django` kernel in Jupyter?

Comment: @AChampion, Good question. Creating conda environment **does not** install `ipykernel` automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I create a kernel for each of my virtual environments. On MacOS Jupyter kernels are located here `$HOME/Library/Jupyter/kernels`. Make sure `ipykernel` is installed in your virtual env.

So `$HOME/Library/Jupyter/kernels/myenv/kernel.json` looks like:

```
{
 "env": { "VIRTUAL_ENV": "/Users/<User>/<myenv>" },
 "argv": [ "/Users/<User>/<myenv>/bin/python3", "-m", "ipykernel", "-f", "{connection_file}" ],
 "display_name": "My Virtual Env",
 "language": "python"
}
```